# Allow us to filter Suggested Edits and Review section by tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, review, suggested-edits

I've had the ability to review suggested edits for a while now, however I don't often do so because the list is usually full of questions about languages and technologies I'm not familiar with or not interested in, and can sometimes be hundreds of questions long.

I would like to help out more, but most of my rep has been gained by questions within a specific technology, so I only feel comfortable reviewing edits within that tag.

Can you allow us to filter suggested edits by tag?

**Edit:**

Actually, can you let us filter the entire Review section by tag, and not just Suggested Edits?

I would find it much more interesting to review questions in tags I'm familiar with and can  understand the question content of, and it would give me a bit of pride to help maintain "my" section of SO.

Comment: If people are using the edit system properly, their suggested edits *should not* be programming language-specific.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A lot of them are things like syntax edits, or terms specific to a technology. I never know if those kind of things are right or not, so leave them for someone else to judge. I feel it would be easier to participate if I could instantly filter the list for questions I am familiar with. As it stands now, I rarely touch the edit queue unless I'm really bored because I don't want to have to wade through a ton of questions that I can't necessarily help with.

Comment: @Rachel here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/217658) of a suggested edit that I think shows your point, but IMHO these should be rejected. The user should have made a comment instead

Comment: @ConradFrix: Is it really Breakpoint Navigator or Debug Navigator?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't have a clue. Does it matter?

Comment: @ConradFrix: It does if the edit is correct.  It's not like code is being changed... It's a menu entry, which, if labeled incorrectly in the answer, would be confusing indeed.

Comment: @ConradFrix I don't like rejecting an edit if it might be right, because then it relies on the person who posted the question/answer to correct the mistake, which doesn't always happen. It also will discourage the editing user from making other edits. I'd much rather leave edits I am unsure about alone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok perhaps a menu entry was a bad example.

Comment: There's more interest in this:  Dupe questions here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/review-beta-questions-by-tag) and here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146156/review-based-on-tag).

Comment: @Rachel If you see an mistake or error in someone else's answer you should post a comment indicating the change.  If the change(s) are too large to post in a comment, or the poster doesn't see or apply your changes, then you should post your own answer with your fixes (and referencing the original if you answer is derived from it).  You can also downvote the mistaken answer if you want.  You should not suggest an edit to fix a mistake.  As a reviewer, if someone suggests an edit to fix a mistake in the content you should reject it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can now filter review queues by tag, post type (i.e. question/answer), or close reason. To create a filter, click the "filter" link beside the heading.

Here it is in action on Stack Overflow's Close Votes queue:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSdkz.png]

Your review filter preferences are saved *per queue* after clicking "Okay".

Comment: Pretty sweet, thanks!

Comment: Awesome. This is easily one of the top 3 most useful features on [so]. I've been maxing my CVs almost every day since.

Comment: is it possible to add this filter to th 10K-tools lists as well? [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/can-we-filter-flags-in-the-10k-tools-by-tag-too?lq=1) [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136614/add-tags-filter-in-the-review-tools-edits-pages)

Comment: "max 3 tags"—this is fairly limited. It would be much better for it to automatically filter based on (a) favourite tags; or (b) tags with a score greater than _n_ in my profile.

Comment: I noticed that the test questions do not honor this filter. If I review just c++ questions and there is suddenly a question properly tagged as R in between, it is kind of unsurprising it’s a test.

Comment: they could add a "same tags as questions" button

Comment: Yes, good. But how about also the possibility of filtering *across all queues*? And more generally, not just tag filtering but searching in general: When on the top-level review page, have another search field that filters the queues. (You would still want access to the normal search field, as well.)

Answer (score 8):

I started to review questions for the first time today and almost immediately ran into this issue.  @Rachel's idea is great, but I might tweak it one way:  Instead of forcing me to select (or unselect) which tags I want to review, why not match tags based upon *my* tags.  For example, I have 34 "html" tags and 34 "html5" tags, so I'm happy to try and review HTML questions.  I don't have any for C or F# or Haskell, so I don't even want to see those questions.  So perhaps you set some minimal threshold, and then only show reviews whose tags match the tag and exceed the threshold.

Either way, I hope someone adds this feature.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to start exactly the same feature request as @Rachel suggested and @yoda improved (close queue).

Current system is dissatisfying. I open review tools and start to read questions / answers and check suggested edits but my experience with many technologies is not good enough to judge if edit should be accepted or rejected. The same happens in close queue.

Why not to allow similar mechanism as favorite-tags in common question queue? If there will be an option to see all unfiltered pending edits / flags as well and numbers in page header will show favorite/all counts it will be great improvement.

You may argue that suggested edits should not be language or technology specific but that is simply not true. Suggested edits contain all kinds of edits including tag wiki edits, community wiki edits and retagging - all mentioned are usually very technology specific.

Answer (score 5):

I think every kind of review function should be filterable by a set of tags different from the user's favorite tags

Answer (score -4):

For the suggested edit queue there is no need for this.  If you are qualified to review posts then the actual content of those posts doesn't matter.  If the edit is changing the content of the post such that its meaning changes you don't need to know, as a reviewer, if it is an improvement or a mistake, it needs to be rejected in either case as either an invalid edit or a radical change.

Comment: I agree with Rachel's point that if there is inaccuracies in the data provided, not the persons opinion, this should be fixed (which would require someone versed in the skill set). Also, as others have commented, this is often not done by the OP based on comments to the question, am also not sure how many researchers read the comments in there entirety to see the needed correction.