# Add tags filter in the Review-Tools-Edits pages

Tags: feature-request, flags, suggested-edits, 10k-tools, tag-filters

There is a thing really missing at the Review-Tools-edit pages.
There're a lot of pending edits (usually > 100) and raised flags (usually > 200).
Most of the flags and edits I can't solve as I have zero knowledge in that tag(Yes, I know approve edits and flags don't have to be related to knowledge, but it's still exhausting to read questions in a "foreign tag").

I would add a tag filter for the flags and edits. This is an exellent way to reduce the flags weight from the mods, and improve the flags handling quality (I'm sure a flag handled by the users of the tag, is better than moderator handled in a "foreign land").

(If that feature request get implemented, I would add a badge for solving X flags\edits in the tag Y, but that's for than.)

Comment: Related: [Allow us to filter Suggested Edits by tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-by-tag)

Comment: @Felix. I believe a lot of what am not i am saying is true regarding to SE. They focus on the commercial side and minor changes rather than the important things, like making SO a good resource.

Comment: Related: [Can we filter Flags in the 10K tools by tag too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/can-we-filter-flags-in-the-10k-tools-by-tag-too)