# Can we filter Flags in the 10K tools by tag too?

Tags: feature-request, tags, 10k-tools, flags

So now that we can [filter the review queues by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149380/158605), can you do the same for the Flag queue?

I have over 10k rep so I get alerted whenever the flag queue gets too high, but encounter the same issue I had with the Review queue: most of my rep has been gained by questions within a specific technology, so I only feel comfortable reviewing flags within that tag.

I would also be much more likely to review flags for in tags I'm familiar with and can understand the question content of then I would be to review flags for technologies I'm not familiar with,  and it would give me a bit of pride to help maintain "my" section of SO.

Comment: +1 - this is I think a great idea.

Comment: Duplicate: [Add tags filter in the Review-Tools-Edits pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136614/168269). A useful addition anyway.

Comment: +1 - This would make a huge difference. 90% of what is flagged is stuff that I cannot make much of a contribution to. I would like to at least be able to *start* my review of the flagged queue by examining stuff in areas I am most familiar with. This feature is sorely missing, IMO. But I am a flag-reviewing newbie, so take my opinion on this so far with a grain of salt.