# Review-beta: Questions by tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow us to filter Suggested Edits and Review section by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-and-review-section-by-tag)

In Review beta, sometimes I get thrown posts from tags that I have close to zero experience with. In general, I can tell if the post contributes to the site or not. In some circumstances - due to my unfamiliarity with the source material - I can't tell whether or not the post should be removed/edited/left alone.

It would be helpful if the system let me review by tag, or at least set tag preferences so I got tags I'm familiar with first. I can definitely be much more helpful reviewing `[ios]` or `[objective-c]` tagged questions than `[ajax]`.

This is especially important because Review is a voluntary I-like-stack-overflow-so-I'll-try-to-help-make-it-better task. The more quickly & easily I/other-less-important-people can get through material the more I feel like I'm helping. And that warm, fuzzy feeling is what it's all about ;)

Comment: I agree!  I'd love to have the 'filter by tags' ability that existed in the old review system!

Comment: I frequent one of the less popular tags on SO, but the _first_ question in the "Review First Posts" queue is _much_ too frequently in my favourite tag for me to believe it was random. I think they're doing this already in some way.

Answer (score 8):

Review by tag would be an easy way to close posts in our area of expertise (I don't even know for sure what `[wpf]` is but I'm at ease with `[CSS]` posts).

It would then be:

- faster,
- less prone to errors,
- more interesting for reviewers,
- possible to spot that `[ubuntu]` and alike are huge candidates to closing (isn't it?),

As for `setting tag preferences`, an easy way would be to use the already existing system of **Favorite tags** (and avoid *Ignore tags*, obviously).