# Review page by specific tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Questions by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/review-beta-questions-by-tag)
>   [Can I have tag preferences to be used to filter the review page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146021/can-i-have-tag-preferences-to-be-used-to-filter-the-review-page)

It would be nice on Review page, especially **Close Votes** to have a filter.

If I start to review some questions it takes me ages until I find questions with my favorite tags. I cannot review in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or in [java](/questions/tagged/java) since I don't know that programming language (although I can see some questions that needs to be closed).

I believe it will be faster to have some filters so reviews can be done faster. It takes too long.

Comment: Well this is ambiguous. On one hand, I agree with you, it' sometimes hard to tell if the question is good or bad if you know nothing on the topic. However a lot of the times questions are closed for a very general reason (like "exact dup"), and you don't need to be an expert on the topic to tell it.

Comment: If you enter Close Votes daily you will see what I mean. I agree Exact dup, but how do I know the question refers some-kind to another same question ? It's time consuming for me and most of the time I simply close because I have something else to do.

Comment: +1 I agree with Mihai, I barely even review anymore because I get a ton of questions I know nothing about.  At first I thought it may automatically be pulling from my favorite tags, when I saw that limiting by tag yourself isn't an option, but now I realize that it isn't done automatically either.  I used to go into the 'drupal' tags all the time to clean up review tasks there, but that's such a small section that I know I'll never get to a 'drupal' tagged first question under the current system.  Do others agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was implemented. There are some filters that someone can apply to each review sections, and maximum 3 tags:

> [image: Review filters]