# Can I have tag preferences to be used to filter the review page?

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Questions by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/review-beta-questions-by-tag)

My current tag preferences highlight new questions in my area of expertise and so I get the chance to review and possibly edit those questions soon after they're posted.

Is there some way for me to specify a different set of tags on the review page to highlight topics that I know enough about to be able to review questions and answers?  I look at some of the first time answers and I have no clue as to whether the answer was a good one or not because I have no familiarity with the topic.

Comment: That would be *very* helpful IMO. Right now it takes too many clicks to find questions I am qualified to review. Even a list, like under the old layout, would be an improvement in terms of usability.