# Reviewing answers based on tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have tag preferences to be used to filter the review page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146021/can-i-have-tag-preferences-to-be-used-to-filter-the-review-page)

I recently reviewed the First Posts in Stack Overflow.
I felt that if the **Reviewing Questions** can be provided with option according to specific tags. If a user whom reviews the questions and answers can easily review his favorite tag answers or he/she familiar with that tag.

Since users can easily review and can easily sort out their type of questions and answers, why can't we implement it?