# Review based on tag

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review-beta: Questions by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142438/review-beta-questions-by-tag)

Is there any way to review based on tags? There are almost 59K questions for close votes for different tags. I am not expert in all tags. Is there anyway we can review questions only for certain tags? I couldn't find one. [image]

Thank you

Comment: @ajax333221: Sort of similar question, but not exact duplicate. Review Suggested Edits sometimes don't require language expertise, but closing I guess for sure required language expertise otherwise might end up voting good question to close.

Comment: you are right, I thought you were talking about suggested edits. I will change it to, related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-by-tag

Comment: @downvoter: Could you explain why you think this question deserve down vote? Is it because of feature request (or) do you see something else?

Comment: Downvotes have a [different meaning on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#link-vote-differences)

Comment: @FelipeAls: That is good to know, as well as while down voting it would be good if you put some words on why you are against to the requested feature. That may help in changing my thought process too.

Comment: Not on meta, again. Downvoters don't like the idea, that's all (note: I didn't upvote or downvote your question)

Comment: @FelipeAls: Not worried above down votes. Just want to understand other people thought son this. Any ways, good to know. Thanks.