# Ask for a filter before a user performs a reviews

Tags: feature-request, review

I recently learned that you can [filter your review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-and-review-section-by-tag) by tag using the `Filter` link next to the queue.  This would have been very useful to know when starting reviews.

Would it be possible to prompt the user before their first review to provide a list of 3-4 tags they would like to use as filters?  Or, if the user preferred, they could simply have a raw unfiltered feed.

The current method requires users to take action to filter questions, so they are less likely to do it.

Comment: I don't know if asking users to filter prior to reviewing is a good idea, but I do agree that the option is way out of sight, we really need to make it more visible somehow.

Comment: in my experience, filtering turned out [especially productive when working in Close Votes queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773 "details are here"). It's quite a pity that this feature is so hard to find; UI definitely sucks

Comment: [**sort this out first**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204269/filtered-review-queue-doesnt-show-any-audits) before everyone starts using filters

Comment: @mehow fixed [Filtered Review Queue doesn't show any audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204592)

Comment: I personally only filter the close vote queue (it's incredibly useful there), I would imagine that filtering any of the other queues just makes it near impossible to find any reviews.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how useful this would be, since a *lot* of users would prefer no filter at all. The system also already attempts to automatically organize the posts you see based on your site activity in order to present posts that are more relevant to you before others.

The filter actually **hides** all posts that don't match your criteria from your personal queue, so you don't even see them. I don't think a lot of users would find that useful or appealing, and they shouldn't be bothered with automated notices about it if they have no intentions of using it. I, personally, would see it as more of a **trick** to get me to only review things in the tags I provide, due to the fact that the system is asking me to provide them. That's not very user-friendly.

As far as asking for 3-4 tags, the current filter implementation only allows for a **maximum** of three tags in the first place (and as stated, you will *only* be shown questions from those tags). There are many users out there that are active in a much wider variety of interests than just three things. The filter is more for finding a *specific type* of post, and fast.

Comment: On many meta-questions I have seen that there are many users who simply didn't know the filter feature existed, so I think that **something** could be done at least to encourage the use of filters for the review queues.