# Review Queues and Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, review, ignored-tags

Steps to Recreate:

1. Have enough rep to use some of the review queues.
2. Ignore a popular tag.
3. Go to your profile-> prefs-> check 'hide ignored tags'.
4. Open a review queue.

You will get questions from your ignored tag(s) in the review queue.

Personally, I ignored a tag on Movies.SE (and Scifi.SE) for a film that is out elsewhere in the world, but not locally.  It's a simple way to avoid being exposed to spoilers.  I then load up the First Posts review queue on Movies.SE, and I get an answer to a question about the end of the film.

Can the review queues be altered to skip posts on your ignored tags when you have the 'hide ignored tags' option enabled?

Comment: Stands to reason that, if you hate the tag and don't wanna see it, then you probably don't want to see it in the review queue either.

Comment: An alternative is to add a separate text box for ignoring tags on the [existing review filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125169/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: ... especially if that text box was *shown in profile preferences next to the other box* to allow preemptive filtering without having to load at least one review item first.

Comment: @rene Yes, thank you! We're planning on adding the ability to exclude Ignored tags as part of our [Review queues overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview).

Answer (score 9):

I think it should be a checkbox, like in this mockup I made:

[image: modified close votes queue filter popup with option "hide ignored tags"]

This way, people who ignore tags because they have spoilers can avoid them in the queues, while people who ignore tags because they are annoyed by seeing questions they can't answer can still review everything without having to change their settings.

This feature could actually increase participation in the queues on some sites, since many people have to stop reviewing entirely because the review queue is so filled with spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

I would not like to see it become an automatic feature because there are many review types that do not need specific domain knowledge. For example, the following improvements can be made by almost anyone, regardless of whether they understand a particular language or technology:

- Grammar and spelling improvements
- Removing tagged words from titles
- Indenting code

To a lesser extent, persons with general knowledge can also retag questions to remove obviously irrelevant tags.

There is a benefit to allowing everyone to see all available review questions: More reviewers can mean more work is accomplished. If we limit reviewing of questions with obscure tags only to people interested in those tags, there may be some questions that never get reviewed properly.

In the specific case that you mentioned, I can see benefit in being able to use the built-in review queue filtering to ignore tags, without the requirement that the ignored review tags be directly linked to the tags ignored elsewhere on the site.

Comment: It might be nice to allow a more persistent, more easily-visible, or more automatic (tied to ignored tags at the click of a link, say) review-ignore feature so those who abhor all sight of PHP or SW: The Force Awakens spoilers can remove those from sight a bit more easily and preemptively than clicking the often-missed `filter` link and making the appropriate selections there.

Answer (score 2):

Or, better still, use both favorite and ignored tags to filter the review queues.