# Improving the Review Queues - Project overview

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, review, announcements

As part of our [Q2 roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/08/q2-community-roadmap/), the Community Product team is working towards improving Review Queues. This project is still in the early stages of discovery. In addition to user research interviews, we are sharing our progress with you today to ask for your feedback before we begin implementation. This is the first post in a series of [new communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346894/new-feedback-tag-product-discovery) we hope to have with the community that uses the new [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery) tag. After we collect community feedback, we will be open to including changes into the next design iteration and continue to share updates with you.

### Objective & Goals

Community moderation is an important part of Stack Exchange and we want to provide the best user experience to those volunteering their time across our sites. In parallel to the [Close Experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience) work, we hope these improvements will better support our curator and moderator communities.

We spoke one-on-one with many active reviewers across the Stack Exchange network, conducted data analysis on current Review Queue usage, and read through just about all of the existing issues raised by our community. We used this qualitative and quantitative data to inform our goals and initial design decisions.

In this redesign, we are exploring ways to improve the overall usability of Review Queues. This includes, but is not limited to:

**Providing guidance and revisiting the banning experience** 
The current on-page instructions are not visible and could be misinterpreted, leading new reviewers to make poor decisions. Inappropriate actions on review tasks or audits can lead to a suspension of privileges with no obvious means of understanding what happened.

**Adding more context to each queue** 
Users are opening browser tabs or using user scripts to view the original post they’re reviewing, other answers, and comments to help make educated decisions.

**Improving filtering and discovery tools** 
The filter feature often goes unnoticed and unused. As it exists now, certain combinations of filters can leave queues empty. It is a poor method to discover or target new tasks.

**Improving queue workflows and pathways** 
On Stack Overflow, the Requires Editing action is sending a surplus of poor, unsalvageable posts to bloat the Help and Improvement queue. H&I reviewers are then limited to either *Skip* or mark the task as *Very Low Quality*, having it return to the Triage queue and creating a frustrating endless loop.

Along with the Triage queue, First Posts and Late Answers are not fulfilling the goals that they were made to accomplish. These queues were intended to give good posts a head start toward success and filter out bad posts, but tasks could see better, faster intervention in other queues.

### What’s next

We’re collecting feedback here on Meta and from 1:1 user interviews. If you have opted-in for user research, you may receive an email invite this week. We’ll be asking questions about how this design may improve (or worsen) review workflows and what you’d like to see in a curated review experience. You can opt-in to future user research opportunities by [enabling Research emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) in your profile settings.

This project is *big*. To focus your feedback, we have broken this announcement into three, digestible posts:

- Main post (*this post*) -  Project overview
- [Improving Review
  Queues - Design overview I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346902/improving-review-queues-design-overview-i-onboarding-and-updating-workflows) - Onboarding and Updated
  Workflows/Paths
- [Improving Review Queues - Design overview
  II](/questions/346903/improving-review-queues-design-overview-ii-changing-review-bans-and-other-new) - Suspension of Privileges and other new features

We’ll be using community feedback to continue to iterate on this work. We look forward to hearing your thoughts and concerns about this project. Please let us know if there are other Review Queue issues you’d like to see addressed as well.

Comment: *"On Stack Overflow, the Requires Editing action is sending a surplus of poor, unsalvageable posts to bloat the Help and Improvement queue. H&I reviewers are then limited to either Skip or mark the task as Very Low Quality, having it return to the Triage queue and creating a frustrating endless loop."* - Heyyy, I remember saying something along those lines! :D

Comment: On Stack Overflow, situation with unsalvageable posts in H&I seems to be indeed worse than you describe. Reviewers who mark the task as Very Low Quality have system cast a VLQ flag on their behalf and it typically [ends at moderators who decline it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285928/839601). Few declines of such flags trigger flag suspension. Essentially the only safe option for garbage in H&I review is Skip, can you imagine what kind of snaked toilet this creates.

Comment: A) I'm so glad this project is happening. Review has been a sore spot for years. B) The iterative approach with gather community feedback along the way is a real winner! I'm gonna model it in my current job. Thank you!

Comment: One fundamental thing to consider: if a queue is never at any point in time empty, then the system design is broken. Queues are supposed to handle peaks in input, so that they can be processed later. But if there is more items entering a queue then leaving, then no amount of queueing will save the system. This is the core reason why the review system occasionally fails completely. The goal must be to _reduce manual review_ by having question wizards, smart scripts, maintenance bots etc.

Comment: Optionally: don't alienate all the people who did these reviews. Moderators and veteran users. SO has consciously and consistently been alienating such users for many years. So eventually you will end up with employees having to do the reviews (or become Quora 2), meaning that you should seek to automate the process so that you don't have to hire as many paid moderators.

Comment: Honestly, I'm really surprised anyone contributes to reviewing at all. It seems an utterly thankless task with occasional horrible pitfalls where you get silently banned, a constant suspicion that you're "cheating" somehow, and no upside whatsoever. So glad to hear it's being worked on.

Comment: As someone who stopped reviewing (on Stack Overflow) very quickly, I am so happy to see attention paid to the queues!

Comment: _“We spoke one-on-one with many active reviewers across the Stack Exchange network, conducted data analysis on current Review Queue usage, and read through just about all of the existing issues raised by our community.”_ — This is great to hear, but have you _used the queues yourselves_ to get a better feeling of where the pain points are?

Comment: @SteveBennett Reviewing is a thankless job indeed, but also a very, *very* important one if you want to maintain content-quality. I review a lot more on Code Review than on Stack Overflow, but that's why I do it. Site quality goes down if I and others stop.

Comment: @SteveBennett Maybe you could persuade yourself that the badges you get for performing reviews makes it worthwhile.

Comment: *Banning Experience* - Yes please. I'm not an idiot but I'm a new reviewer - and I've already been banned twice, and I was actually trying to be useful. I've basically rarely touched the queue since my second ban, because I don't want to get banned a third time. Very demotivating. Having some guidance or better support here would be great.

Comment: It is probably worth talking to people who have done review queue work in the past but not for some time; people who are active reviewers are evidently not finding it painful enough to cause them to abandon it.  I suspect if you look at active users who are eligible to run queues, only a small percentage actually do, and figuring out the reasons the rest of them don't, and fixing those, should be an important part of any overhaul on the review system.

Comment: Most of my activity is on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com which obviously has different queues. It could do with something to mark questions unsalvageable. The Active questions is full of unanswered or not accepted answers, promoted by the "Community" often for obsolete operating systems with no prospect of answers.

Comment: How about getting a reward for actually spending time reviewing, closing and fixing things. It's a never ending job, it **never** stops. All the new people posting the same "I want this implemented, can someone help?" that we need to close is tiresome, and we don't really get a reward for cleaning up the site. Perhaps get 0.1 points for every successfully closed (voted) question etc? That would be more valuable than "tidying up the queues" which is probably needed, but in all honesty, feeling some kickback for actually cleaning up the site would be ever better. //SO user&"moderator"

Comment: _Banning Experience_ - when you ban a user, how about also stopping the showing of the red "high volume" dot. Also, in place of the unhelpful 'There are no review queues available to you' how about a link to the review area [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review) so that we can see what the issue was?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could earn the privilege of not getting "tested" after some number of reviews.  It is another thing that adds to the "thankless" feeling.

Comment: @Katie I would be careful about this. I did tens thousands reviews in different queues on differrent sites and I fail review audits very infrequently, maybe once in few months but I still would prefer getting these because audits help me control whether I am sufficiently attentive

Comment: Any thoughts on dealing with flatly incorrect audits? I've noticed an uptick in them, and I think several users [have also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/add-an-i-dont-understand-option-for-review-audits). It's a little demoralizing to be dinged for an audit, especially when the question isn't even borderline. Anecdotally, I've seen that issue mostly very recently, though I can't say with certainty that anything changed.

Answer (score 152):

I'll leave specific notes on your design overview posts, but wanna drop my overall impressions here: as someone who has spent a considerable amount of time and energy on these systems since their inception, I believe you've correctly identified the areas that most need focus (whether that focus is needed due to serious problems in their current behavior, or due to missed opportunities).

You've done your homework, and it shows.

Answer (score 14):

> mobile review screens
> unusable for so long
> under way, in progress

Happy to report that UX refresh work for review task screens (including responsive design) is underway.

Answer (score 7):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

> Please let us know if there are other Review Queue issues you’d like to see addressed as well

Yes, mobile usage.

Currently, it's  nearly impossible to review using a mobile device.

With all due respect to help center and explaining to people how review works, it's more important, in my humble opinion, to let the people who already know how to review to do it  from a mobile device.

The responsive design project appears to be stuck, didn't see any update for months.

I'm sure there is a pending feature request for this, search currently not working so I'll add a link later.

Comment: The UX refresh for the review task screens is planned to be fully responsive, will be tested on mobile. This phase of the project is getting started right now.

Comment: Wish I could add a bounty to your comment here @YaakovEllis. One long awaited upgrade I'm really thankful for!

Comment: @Luuklag [here ya go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356168/51)

Comment: @Luuklag only 100?! ;)

Comment: Feel free to add more tomorrow @Shadow10YearsWizard ;)

Comment: Your turn @Shadow10YearsWizard ;)

Comment: @Luuklag done! Too bad newlines aren't preserved in bounty reason, lol. (tried to make it funny)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard paragraphs are supported I think?

Comment: @Luuklag didn't work for me, and can't really test it...

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks/120346#120346

Comment: @Luuklag ohhh... neat!