# Please re-consider adding the ability to select 'ignored' tags in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-filters

The recent [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/) announcement indicated that no additional features beyond what was pushed out as of today would be implemented as part of the [Review Queue Overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351117/plans-for-updates-to-review-queues). Unfortunately, that means one of the best new features, in my opinion, is getting dropped.

Early on, it was mentioned/demo'd that users would be able to select up to three tags they didn't want to see any questions for in the Close Vote and Reopen Vote review queues. Tired of seeing [php](/questions/tagged/php) questions? Don't want to deal with another one of those [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) debates? This was the feature for you!

Please re-consider adding this feature to those review queues!

<sub>Note: in case this request looks familiar, it was originally a [general feedback answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369020#369020), but it was suggested by staff to post a separate request. I [did so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369042/253521), and it was suggested again to make it a separate question altogether, so here we are...</sub>

Comment: It's also been around before: [Review Queues and Ignored Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178378/179041)

Comment: @Robotnik That's similar but not quite the same; the feature they planned for the recent review queues would have enabled us to choose specific tags to ignore in review, independent of our ignored tags on the site. It would not be as effective an implementation, in my opinion, to simply grab whatever ignored *site* tags one has and use that list, because one can choose to simply 'grey out' ignored *site* tags, rather than hide them altogether.