# Add ability to configure preferences so I only review questions with certain tags

Tags: feature-request

I don't mind reviewing questions/edits periodically, but I end up skipping a lot of them. It would be great if I could just sign up to review questions with specific tags as a preference. I understand that many reviews have more to do with clarity, etc. than technology, but I think having the ability to filter what things I review would make me a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-pollination that happens in the current system is helpful. Many of the questions have issues that people with *any* technical background can answer. For example, grammar, spelling, formatting and clarity problems are common to all tags.

Additionally, people with diverse skill sets may recognize something in a question that warrants an additional tag. If editing is confined to answers following a particular tag who don't have the background to recognize a cross-category subtlety, the question may be unnecessarily confined to that tag.

When you encounter a question that requires expertise outside of your skill set, there is little harm in skipping it. Someone else with the required background will eventually see and edit it.

Comment: This might be good for suggested edits, vlq etc, but not the close queue.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a duplicate question and here was the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149380/158825

"You can now filter review queues by tag, post type (i.e. question/answer), or close reason. To create a filter, click the "filter" link beside the heading."

I wish this were a bit easier though. Seems like it would be in the prefs section.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to filter the reviews seen in each specific Review Queue.  Go to that Review Queue page (Review => Close Votes for example).  Below the Stack Overflow logo and to the right of the label for the queue (e.g. "Close Votes"), click on the "filter" link.  You can add up to 3 tags to filter by.

Comment: Thanks! Beat you by less than 2 seconds I think with my answer below (or you beat me to it possibly and I just didn't see it at first). I just wish this were simpler with just a user pref.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver No, it looks like you beat me to it by 9 seconds.

Comment: Maybe due to time diliation. :)

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver According to the mouseover over "answered 5 mins ago" for our respective answers, I see "2013-05-15 21:19:33Z" for your answer and "2013-05-15 21:19:42Z" for my answer.

Comment: I wasn't disputing what you said about the 9 seconds, I was just trying to be humorous saying that perhaps one of us was moving quickly enough to cause dilation of time, per general relativity, which is probably an outdated concept. I failed.

Comment: Of course! Time dilation!  Now I get it.

Comment: When you type close to the speed of light, an extra 'i' creeps into dilation.