# Offer a "I don't know enough about this subject" skip-button

Tags: feature-request, review

When I review new users' answers I sometimes realize that I don't know enough about the question's topic to properly judge it's appropriateness. Sure there is the `skip` button, but I consider that more of a "I don't feel like reading through all this"-button. A separate button à la `needs expert attention` that causes the post to earlier show up in the review queue of someone more proficient in the question's tags and later in everyone else's (some kind of judgement-difficulty adjustment if you will) might be helpful here.

Comment: Surely this is just semantics? Does it really matter _why_ you skip? What exactly would such a specific button bring? What's the added value? And why not "I am really bored with this question" or "TLDR"? Why stop with one?

Comment: @Oded The difference would be to whom else's review queue's _top_ or _bottom_ this review task would be moved

Comment: How so? Reviews don't really take your tags into account, as far as I know.

Comment: Reviewers can *already* filter the queue on tags. You can too.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we need a way to flag reviews as things that require subject knowledge? The problem with that is that it is difficult to determine who is a subject matter expert (and ensure they go to the review queues).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really? Where is this functionality?

Comment: The problem here is that the first posts queue is almost always completely empty. There's no sorting to happen.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not restricted to that, what about edits that claim to add relevant context, or close-votes due to a question being too simple?

Comment: @Kreiri: Right next to the queue title: `Review | Suggested Edits  filter`. Click on `filter`.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler you can already filter by tags or close vote types. No need to add an extra easy/hard axis

Comment: @Oded Well some review tasks are not exactly trivial, so it _might_ be helpful to pre-judge the difficulty for others even if one can't judge about the quality of the post/edit itself

Comment: @JanDvorak I'd e.g. know whether a [tag:git] question deserved being closed or not, but once [tag:regex] is involved, I can't

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - So? Skip any that you don't feel qualified to review. I don't see a need for an _extra_ "handle with care - only for experts".

Comment: @Oded Sure enough that's what I currently do. Well, it's just been an idea, and honestly not one that I'd be dying to see...

Comment: I like the idea in that it tells people **"If you don't know enough about the subject, skip it."** That doesn't seem to be totally clear to everybody, as witnessed by the astounded reactions of (reasonably intelligent-seeming) people on Meta when confronted with the fact. Maybe the message can be subtly integrated somewhere without actually creating another button?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Or some hover text? Maybe the skip button should clarify that using it will yield no disadvantage towards a badge - honestly, I've been tempted to approve/reject a couple of tasks just for the sake of not appearing to be lazy, but I didn't give in and did skip (end of proud speech)

Comment: Gee, talk about downvote-bait m-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, I really do not see the need to complicate the UI further for this.

You can already filter the queue by tag; if you feel you cannot review first posts or close reasons outside of your field of expertise, just filter the queue to only show you tags you care about:

[image: review queue filter]

Just hit 'skip' and be done with it.

Comment: Has that filter option always been there? It's very useful, never even noticed that before!

Comment: It has been there for quite some time now.

Comment: @JonW: It's been available [since October last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/allow-us-to-filter-suggested-edits-and-review-section-by-tag).

Comment: I didn't spot that one... Though an option to respect the interesting/ignored tags might be helpful as well

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It would be a nice feature to use your interesting/ignored tags, but that would still be a lot of context switching between reviews, as it might jump between (for example) `git` and `java`.  Not to mention that some people literally have hundreds of interesting/ignore tags, which would slow down the query considerably.  I think it's better to just explicitly pick a tag (or two or three) to focus on at a time.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I haven't reached the 3k to assist with those 56k close votes at SO but that's a really intimidating number, so respecting the ignored tags might really be helpful. Hm, what about [allowing 1k users to cast quarter-close votes in the review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186984/allow-1k-users-to-review-close-votes-counting-as-0-25-actual-close-votes) by the way?