# Abandon the review grind-badges

Tags: feature-request, review, badges

The bronze review badges are fine, but the higher tiers do simply encourage grossly negligent reviewing too much. Not to say that reviewing shouldn't be appreciated, but having made the internet a better place should be incentive enough for anyone who honestly wants to review and not just grind through to a shiny badge.

To quote Nicol Bolas' [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149624/146482):

> As long as there's a shiny gold badge in it, someone will grind out reviews just to get it. Take away the incentive, and many people may stop reviewing altogether. Perhaps the latter might be a better option; at least then, you're getting people who actually care about reviewing involved.

Comment: Inspired by [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149624/146482)

Comment: No! I'm three days from four Steward badges...!

Comment: @michaelb958 Don't take it personally, it's [for the good of many](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xa6c3OTr6yA)