# From bull to bear - what can be done to decrease the mass of close votes?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

[image: 59.6k close votes!]

Sure enough a lot of work is done on the [close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), which steadily approaches a total of a first *million* all-time reviews. But unfortunately, the queue still seems to *grow* at a rate of approximately 1k additional close votes every four days (crude average over the last week, but [the queue has been increasing from the very start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151996/146482)). Sure enough there are mechanisms to assist reviewers to more or less efficiently crawl that queue, e.g. by filtering tags, but apparently this is not enough, so

> What further measures can be taken to *decrease* the close votes queue without compromising it?

Is reviewing still too tedious and improvements in the queue could help? Or do we need more reviewers? How many of those who can do actually review the close votes queue regularly? (And how is a virtual badge supposed to motivate them into spending their precious time?) [Could lower-rep users assist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186984/146482)

Comment: Order them by number of close votes DESC?

Comment: The main issue with this queue on [so] is psychological - people see the size and don't want to get started on an endless job...

Comment: @Oded you may be partly correct. However, when I jumped into it, the count went down gradually from 55.xK to 49.xK. Then something happened and the list started growing again and I gave up (for the time being).

Comment: @AzizShaikh - Exactly my point. "I gave up" - and so did many others. If people didn't give up, the queue would keep shrinking...

Comment: I don't think it's that psychological reason (but obviously I could be wrong). Judging close votes is more work than judging suggested edits; and judging "duplicate" votes even requires you to process _two_ posts.

Comment: @Oded It was going down and I was dreaming that one day it will be in reasonable limits. Then it stopped going down. :(

Comment: @S.L.Barth - That is part of the issue, yes.

Comment: Didn't it go back up because the age limit of posts in that queue was pushed back even further?

Comment: @fedorqui: I'd have thought we'd want to handle recent ones first since the questions would be receiving more attention. Old ones that are just to tidy the site could be done after.

Comment: @Oded It's not the queue size that I'd consider [discouraging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus), it's rather the net balance of an ever-growing queue that makes me e.g. wonder [why only the >3kers should carry that burden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186984/146482)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: I wonder then if the age limit should be removed so we get the full, massive queue that at least goes down (assuming items are actioned faster than added).

Comment: one of my reasons for giving up the close vote reviews is its slowness when filtered - for me it's unacceptable to wait a (felt, didn't measure) minute until the next comes up.

Comment: Try to design a machine learning algorithm similar to the prediction challenge from last summer? The algorithm could try to order questions based on their likelihood to be closed...

Comment: @kleopatra: One minute?! What filters do you have? I filter to include only a single tag ([tag:C#]) and it takes less than one second.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett single tag as well, swing or java mostle. But as I said, that's a very subjective value :-) Anyway, it's perceptible much longer than without filter. Could be just me, but I'm allergic against waiting.