# Does the close review queue hate R questions or does it just hate me?

Tags: discussion, bug, review, vote-to-close

It was mentioned in the comments of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188542/from-bull-to-bear-what-can-be-done-to-decrease-the-mass-of-close-votes) recent Meta question that a user was experiencing long delays between questions in the close review queue.

I have been experiencing the same thing, when I use as a filter just the single tag [r](/questions/tagged/r). I've tested it with many other single language tags (C, C#, PHP, Javascript, Java, etc.) and they all seem very fast. The other user said they were seeing slow transitions for [java](/questions/tagged/java) which doesn't happen for me. Only with [r](/questions/tagged/r).

I've been timing it, and the transition between questions is generally 10-15 seconds, which is pretty darn slow.

So, is it something I did, or is this a bug of some sort?

Comment: I just did a few in [tag:r] and had no problems/delays.  I have seen delays in the past in various close votes, but I assume it's either random slowdowns or something about the particular question perhaps.

Comment: @Joe I guess it's just me, then, since it's still painfully slow when I try it.

Comment: I occasionally see long delays between questions in the other queues, regardless of tags. It seems to happen when the queue is highly trafficked and almost empty, suggesting a large amount of contention might cause the delay. It seems unlikely that this would be the cause for close votes, though, since there are plenty of reviews to go around in that queue. Unless there are a lot of users hankering to close r questions.